# How to get the email ID from the look up column in SharePoint workflow

Tags: sharepoint-fields

I have a Lookup list which contain some information about user including emailID.
Lookup column has been used in another list A . A workflow has been triggered in creating a item in list A. Now I want to send an email to the user based on the lookup column,the email ID is present in lookup list

Comment: The list which has lookup (A List), you can also select email column while creating lookup column If that email column is single line of text.
So that in list A you will have both columns Lookup column and Email column.
In workflow directly you can select CurrentItem of email column from List A in Send Email action window.

Answer (score 1):

The list which has lookup (A List), you can also select email column while creating lookup column If that email column is single line of text. So that in list A you will have both columns Lookup column and Email column. In workflow directly you can select CurrentItem of email column from List A in Send Email action window

Comment: Please accept f you are okay with this :)